# Will there be a re-skinning of this stackexchange site when it comes out of beta?

Tags: discussion

The design of gaming.stackexchange.com seems to be more like a schoolwork or homework type design. What does this have to do with gaming? Is this just temporary?

Answer (score 3):

This is the temporary skin for all beta stackexchange sites. The admins don't want to design a skin for sites in beta in case they don't make it out of beta.

See [this meta stackoverflow question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55529/will-all-stack-exchange-sites-look-the-same/55542#55542).

Comment: Now is not a bad time to actually start throwing out ideas for how the site should look. It's the last thing on our Top 7 that we haven't even looked at, yet it's one of the largest and most important aspects. It's probably the size of the job, though, that is why we haven't discussed it yet.

Comment: Sadly, I'm bad with graphics.